# Change UIBarButtonIcon in an if and else statement in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Inside of an If and else statement I want to change the custom image of my BarButtonItem. How can I Do these by default I already have one custom Image but know I want that under some circumstances it changes to another custom Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your images in Assets.xcassets you can do this:

```
if something {

    yourBarButtonItem.image = imagename

} else {

    yourBarButtonItem.image = anotherimagename

}
```

that should work. Else, if you have your image just in a folder inside your project you can to this:

```
if something {

    yourBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "imagename.extension")

} else {

    yourBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "imagename.extension")

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:) @Lucas Palaian